# Return unique results in query builder

Tags: symfony, doctrine, dql

I have a query builder for my form field so it must return an instance of a query builder. Currently, some of the results are duplicates of each other with minor differences. I want to only display unique results based on a particular column `fileName/qf.fileName`.

I currently have:

```
'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $repository) use ($options) {
    return $repository
        ->createQueryBuilder('qf')
        ->join('qf.quote', 'q', Expr\Join::WITH, 'q.client = :client')
        ->setParameter('client', '3');
},
```

and I want the results to be unique based of the column `qf.fileName`. I have tried using `distinct` but I believe you need to select a particular column which doesn't work for me because I want to return the entire entity.

I have also tried group by but I get the following error:

> GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column

Any help would be great, thanks.

*Ignore the hard-coded client!*

**EDIT:**

So the property doesn't exist on the entity, it's being used to present existing data on the form, so we utilise the `by_reference` attribute.

The data presented to the front end is generated from the query builder.

```
->add('example', EntityType::class, [
   'class' => Example::class,
   'multiple' => true,
   'required' => false,
   'by_reference' => false,
   'expanded' => true,
   'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $repository) use ($client) {
        return $repository
            ->createQueryBuilder('ex')
            ->join('ex.quote', 'e', Expr\Join::WITH, 'e.client = :client')
            ->setParameter('client', $client->getId());
    },
]);
```

Comment: You should persist with your GROUP BY, you just forgot one or few columns in your group by.
Try with a `->select()` with your group by

Answer (score 0):

This won't work as Enities cannot be hydrated from an aggregated result set. You need to fall back to a custom Type extending ChoiceType and use a custom DataTransformer to refetch the selected Entity after Form submit.

Comment: You able to explain further? I've edited my question to include the entire field. Essentially the data presented on the front end is from the query builder in the field. I tried creating a data transformer but the data passed to the transform method is empty, I'm assuming this is because the data is grabbed from the query builder. Any ideas?

Comment: It's not about form, it's about Doctrine is unable to hydrate entities from an aggregated sql query as it cannot be mapped correctly.

Comment: I'm still unsure on your suggestion to solve the problem. Sorry lol